# Header for environ on Mac

Tags: c++, macos

How could I find out the header for "environ" on Mac? I want to include it in my project. Thank you!
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man7/environ.7.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no header file; as the manpage says you simply need to declare it yourself:

```
#include <iostream>

extern char **environ;

int main()
{
    for (unsigned i = 0; environ[i]; i++)
        std::cout << environ[i] << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

You might be better off sticking to `genenv()` and `setenv()` unless you need to do wholesale manipulation, for example, before passing it to a child process.

Comment: Thank you:) Your approach worked. But I think the `environ` should exist in a header file, or at least defined somewhere.